# Camunda modular design

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I want to manage a huge workflow in Camunda.

I have decided to split this into different processes like Create, Configuration, Review & Confirm. Each of these processes have 10 to 15 tasks. These processes should be executed in sequence.

If I want to design my workflow like this, how will I link each process. What is the proper way for Camunda modular design.

Answer (score 3):

You would probably go with some kind of [SubProcess](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/). If you plan to model different processes you most likely will use [Call Activities](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/bpmn20/subprocesses/call-activity/) and execute them one ofter another in some kind of root process.

Beware of the fact that each sub process starts its own process instance and thus you have to handle different execution scopes. That will be relevant if you request information from the system like e.g. the List of UserTasks. You can not use the *processInstanceId* of the root process in this case and will have to use a *businessKey*.

You also have to handle the process variables and decide which variables you want to propagate to the sub process.

Comment: I want to design different processes. So as you said if I use call activity, will I be defining each of my processes in different bpmn files? How will it be? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Ani Did you read the documentation I linked to - especially about Call Activities? Yes - you can define each process in an own BPM file. To call a process you will use the process definition id in the Call Activity (Quote: `A call activity is a regular activity that requires a calledElement which references a process definition by its key. In practice, this means that the id of the process is used in the calledElement`). Have a try and raise new concrete questions on specific problems. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for comment with using `businessKey` in Call Activity to query further for e.g. active user tasks (including those from sub-execution). Helped me a lot!

For others stumbling upon that: just make sure your Call Activity has _Business Key_ option checked - this propagates `businessKey` from processInstance to newly created one resolved in Call Activity.